# Discrepancy over matrix exponential

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to compute $\large e^A$ for $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a \\
0 & 0  \end{array} \right)$

Using $\large e^A = \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k$

Writing out the first few terms of this, I get...

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a \\
0 & 0  \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  \end{array} \right) +    . . . $

So clearly I get $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a \\
0 & 1  \end{array} \right)$ as my answer. However, WolframAlpha says differently:

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28%7B%7B0,a%7D,%7B0,0%7D%7D%29)

What's going on?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp%28%7B%7B0%2Ca%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%7D%7D%29

Comment: It interprets $e^A$ as the componentwise exponentiation.

Comment: Mathematica (the backend for Wolfram|Alpha) allows a function to be applied to an array of any depth by simply applying the function to each entry.  A matrix is an array of depth $2$ (list of lists), so the exponential function $x \mapsto e^x$ is applied to each entry of the matrix.

Comment: thank you all so much, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most computer programs interpret e^matrix componentwise. In matlab, for example, to do the matrix exponential, you use exp**m**, not exp (which does componentwise exponentiation).

[This link](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixExp.html) tells you how to use MatrixExp in Mathematica (and Wolfram Alpha) to do matrix exponentiation.